# CREATE TABLE query crashes

Tags: sqlite

I want to create a table with 2 number fields that are both unique.. Here is the query I tried:

```
CREATE TABLE Favorite {
Indexx INTEGER,
Numberr INTEGER,
UNIQUE(Indexx,Numberr)
}
```

But it crashes.. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE Favorite (
Indexx INTEGER,
Numberr INTEGER,
UNIQUE(Indexx,Numberr)
)
```

This should solve your problem. It was `{` and `}` brackets that causes the problem.

Comment: @Tichodroma thanks for the edit.. wondering what you have edited?

Comment: You can click on [the link above my avatar](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12346959/revisions) to see the details of my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Use `(` and `)`, not `{` and `}` as described in the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html).